# Restore sound configuration

Tags: restore, alsa, ubuntu-11.10

After install some packages, I don't have sound! I installed Rosegarden, VMPK (piano software), Drumstick Virtual Piano and TiMidity. At the beginning, all works fine, but when I reset my PC, I don't listen anything.

I would like how can I reinstall Alsa. I want to have it completely new, all the settings by default, for example when Ubuntu is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already visited [official Ubuntu Sound troubleshoot page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)?

You may want to check default sound output device in your system, as new packages could add new devices and set them as primary/default.

Second, check whether your primary channel is not muted, for example with `alsamixer` console utility.

Answer (score 2):

All the alsamixer settings are stored in: /var/lib/alsa/asound.state
To restore alsa settings to factory default in raspberry pi 3:

Take a good alsa file, like: 
/MyBackup/asound.state

Make a backup of the bad alsa file:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/alsa/asound.state /var/lib/alsa/asound.state.bak5
```

Copy the good file instead of the bad one:

```
sudo cp /MyBackup/asound.state /var/lib/alsa/asound.state
```

And then run the following line ( the last number in the line is the sound card number ). The following command will read the file "/home/pi/temp1/asound.state" and put it's settings in the soundcard's registers. You can see in realtime the changes being applied in alsamixer app.

```
sudo alsactl restore 1
```